# Adding an Edit.php link to the end of each returned row

Tags: php, mysql, web, edit

I am trying to add a link to the end of each returned result row from the mysql database that will send me to another php page which will allow me to edit the data from the row. The problem is I cant find which part of the code I should be adding the link code to so that no matter how many results are returned an edit link will be present at the end of each row.

Here is the php code I am currently using to retrieve the results.

```html
<?php 
  
 echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
 echo "<tr><th>Booking Ref</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Contact Number</th><th>Booked Date</th><th>Adults</th><th>Juniors</th><th>Paintballs</th><th>Edit</th></tr>";
 
 class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
  function __construct($it) { 
   parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
  }
 
  function current() {
   return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
  }
 
  function beginChildren() { 
   echo "<tr>"; 
  } 
 
  function endChildren() { 
   echo "</tr>" . "\n";
  } 
 } 
 
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "login";
 
 $u_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
 
 try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT booking_id, fname, lname, phone_number, date, adults, juniors, paintballs FROM bookings INNER JOIN users ON users.user_name = bookings.user_name WHERE users.user_name = '" . $u_name . "'"); 
  $stmt->execute();
 
  // set the resulting array to associative
  $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
  foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
   echo $v;   
  }
 }
 catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
 $conn = null;
 echo "</table>";
  
 ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place it in `endChildren()` method.
But I'm not sure at all how you can access the row data (you'll obviously need the row id to edit it).

Comment: Thanks for that, it creates an Edit link for the resulted amount of rows but its appearing outside the table the results are shown in like so:

Edit Edit Edit
Row 1 Data Data Data Data -
Row 2 Data Data Data Data -
Row 3 Data Data Data Data -

Comment: Ahh i just figured it out I surrounded it with <td></td> tags and it worked brilliantly thanks a lot its had my head in a spin for the last couple of hours can't believe it was all because of that haha!